# Как вызвать node.js из bash скрипта

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

Возникла нужда в том что бы написать прогу для легкого управления хостами в apache2 на linux. Раз прога чисто для меня, то захотелось её сделать на node.js. В папке /usr/local/bin создаю файл apache(В этой папке уже хранятся остальные мной созданные скрипты, которые отлично работают). Так же там создал файл virtualhost.js. Была такая идея: пишу в терминале sudo apahce create test.
Файл apache вызывает файл virtualhost.js и передаёт ему аргументы.(node virtualhost.js ...). Но терминал выдаёт что node не найден, хотя он есть.
В чём проблема? Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Попробуйте указать полный путь до интерпретатора:  `/usr/bin/node virtualhost.js`. Где именно он находится можно узнать так: `whereis node`

Comment: Спасибо, но неужели нету возможности вызывать node без указания полного пути. У меня node лежит в папке nvm/6.0.0/node. Тоесть если я обновлю node, в скрипте будет юзаться node версии 6.0.0

Comment: В переменной ```PATH``` путь до ```node``` прописан?

Comment: Переменная PATH только в винде вроде?

Comment: Ага, папки, мышь и окна в майкрософт придумали ))) Нет. Эта переменая есть в любой современнной ОС.

Comment: @RTK оформите свой комментарий как ответ

Comment: а можно добавить `#!/usr/bin/env node` в первую строчку js-файла

Answer (score 1):

При выполнении скрипта через `sudo`, скрипт не учитывает переменную среды `$PATH` по соображениям безопасности. Вместо этого используется `secure_path`, который можно посмотреть так: `sudo grep secure_path /etc/sudoers`. Изменять его нежелательно.

Для решения проблемы необходимо в скрипте написать полный путь до `node`, например: `/usr/bin/node virtualhost.js`

Узнать полный путь до `node` в системе можно с помощью команды `which node` (или `whereis node`).